# how to change strings/labels in a csv file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My code is given below. I have a input_df.csv file as given below:

```
input_df = [time:[1,2,3,4],v1=[10,20,30,40],p1=[1,2,3,4],v2=[10,20,30,40],p2=[1,2,3,4]]
```

I want to change the title of two strings in above dataframe. That is, p1 and p2 to i1, i2. I tried following way:

```
import re    
with open('input_df.csv', 'r') as f:
    my_csv_text = f.read()
new_csv_str = re.sub('p1', 'i1', my_csv_text)
new_csv_str1 = re.sub('p2', 'i2', my_csv_text)
with open('modifiedInput_df.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_csv_str),f.write(new_csv_str1)
with open('modifiedInput_df.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_csv_str1)
print(pd.read_csv('modifiedInput_df.csv').head())
```

The actual output is

```
time  v1  p1  v2   i2
```

I wanted something like

```
time  v1  i1  v2   i2
```

My question is: p1 is failed to convert to i1. In my above code, I have called the open function twice. Looks like, last one is only executed. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,4],'v1':[10,20,30,40],'p1':[1,2,3,4],'v2':[10,20,30,40],'p2':[1,2,3,4]})
```

or:

```
input_df = pd.read_csv('input_df.csv')
input_df = input_df.rename(columns={'p1':'i1','p2':'i2'})
input_df
```

Would this work for you?